# Send email get stuck at transport.connect

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

This is the code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.mydomain.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "myemail@mydomain.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", "mypassword");

Session sendSession = Session.getInstance(properties);

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sendSession);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail@mydomain.com"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(content);

Transport transport = sendSession.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect("mail.mydomain.com", 465, "mydomain.com@mydomain.com", "mypassword");
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

These are the SSL/TLS setting:

```
Outgoing Server: mail.mydomain.com
SMTP Port: 465
```

Executing the above code, it get stuck at:

```
transport.connect("mail.mydomain.com", 465, "mydomain.com@mydomain.com", "mypassword");
```

and nothing happen.

Why it get stuck at `connect` and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you sure that it stops at ```connect```?

Comment: @Umeshwaran, I'm using debugger and it stops there.

Comment: Try changing the ```mail.smtp.starttls.enable``` to false and try sending the mail

Comment: @Umeshwaran, the problem still persist.

Comment: Try changing the ```properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");``` to ```properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");``` i.e ```smtps``` to ```smtp``` and try sending mail

Comment: Looks like the response from the mail server is not reaching your program. You should check the firewall and proxy settings.
Try to connect from the command line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030820/2135838

Comment: @Umeshwaran, still :(

Comment: @Sascha, if i'm using gmail, it works. But with mydomain not.

Comment: add ```mail.debug=true``` property and check the debug trace

Comment: @KunLun Have you checked if a normal mail client can connect with your mail server?

Comment: @Sascha, yes I checked and it is.

Comment: @KunLun Did you the check from the command line?
Also, you should set a connection timeout.
properties.setProperty("mail.connectiontimeout", "30000");
properties.setProperty("mail.timeout", "30000");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

At `Transport transport = sendSession.getTransport("smtp");`

Instead of `smtp` should be `smtps`

Thanks to everybody who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `mail.transport.protocol` value from `smtps` to `smtp`.

You are trying to use port 465 which is for smtp . So you have to change the protocol to `smtp` . You are trying to start TLs with secure mode but you are using simple smtp port.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
.....
```

Try changing it and send mail.